# Vue How to Trigger Child Component on Submitting Form

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my PhoneLineNumberComponent. It's running perfectly, but I want when a user clicks the button on parent component, the child component form will be loaded.
PhoneLineNumberComponent is my child component
and ButtonComponent is my parent component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form v-for="(line,index) in lines" v-bind:key="index">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="row">
                       <div class="form-group">
                       <input v-model="line.number"
                                   float-label="Phone Number"
                                   numeric-keyboard-toggle
                                   placeholder="5551234567"
                                   type="text"
                                   class="form-control"
                                   value="" />

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button type="button" v-if="index + 1 === lines.length"  @click="addLine">Add</button>
                <button type="button" @click="removeLine(index)">Delete</button>


            </div>
            </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'PhoneNumberLineComponent',
        data() {
            return {
                lines:[],
                blockRemoval: true,
                index:[],
            }
        },
        watch: {
            lines() {
                this.blockRemoval = this.lines.length <= 1
            }
        },
        methods: {
            addLine() {
                let checkEmptyLines = this.lines.filter(line => line.number === null)
                if (checkEmptyLines.length >= 1 && this.lines.length > 0) return
                this.lines.push({
                    countryCode: null,
                    number: null,

                })
            },
            removeLine(lineId) {
                if (!this.blockRemoval) this.lines.splice(lineId, 1)
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.addLine()
        }

    }
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

This is my ButtonComponent. I want when a user clicks the button on ButtonComponent child component PhoneLineNumber shall be triggered.

```
<template>


    <div>

        <PhoneNumberLineComponent></PhoneNumberLineComponent>


    </div>


</template>

<script>
    import PhoneNumberLineComponent from './PhoneNumberLineComponent';
    export default {
        name:'ButtonComponent',
        components: {
            PhoneNumberLineComponent
        },
        data() {
            return {
                lines: [],
                blockRemoval: true,
                index:[],
            }
        },

    };
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a button on the ButtonComponent

Comment: Why did you re-edit your post to put in the incorrect component name again after I fixed it? It's just confusing, your code references "PhoneNumberLineComponent", but your text description of the problem has it as "PhoneLineNumberComponent" and later just "Component PhoneLineNumber" - neither of which exist in your code examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set control clicked data like `toggleShow` with boolean type and use `v-if` for your component trigger

```
<template>


    <div>

        <PhoneNumberLineComponent v-if="toggleShow"></PhoneNumberLineComponent>

        <button @click="toggleShow = !toggleShow">Button</button>
    </div>


</template>

<script>
    import PhoneNumberLineComponent from './PhoneNumberLineComponent';
    export default {
        name:'ButtonComponent',
        components: {
            PhoneNumberLineComponent
        },
        data() {
            return {
                lines: [],
                blockRemoval: true,
                index:[],
                toggleShow: false
            }
        },

    };
</script>
```